# How to use IF else condition in SQL.?

Tags: sql, oracle, if-statement, where-clause

I have two will parameters ( non - Mandatory ) from users, say start_date and end_ date.
Case 1 :if users doesn't give bothe values,query will fetch values
Case 2 : user give start period then query fetch value that was greater than or equal to start date
Case 3: user giving both ,then query fetch inbetween records
Case 4 : user give end date only,then query need to fetch value less than or equal to end date

My query

```
select Reg_date,employees,years from employee 
Where 
IF start_date != ""
  IF end_date != ""
     Where Reg_date >= start_date and Reg_date <= end_date
  Else
     Where Reg_date >= start_date
  END
ELSE
 IF end_date != ""
   Where Reg_date <= End_date
 End
END
```

can you please anyone is there syntax am using is correct..I need to execute this in server.So I am unable to run in any test_env.User can give start_date and end_date value...

Comment: is it mysql or oracle?

Comment: oracle and mysql are two different platforms.  I would also recommend reading a basic SQL tutorial

Comment: @OldProgrammer - It is oracle

Comment: Oracle doesn't allow double quotes around string literals, you have to use single quotes.

Comment: Is there other syntax / selection method was corect .?

Comment: @Barmar And, in Oracle, `''` is the same as `NULL` (and any comparison to `NULL` is always false, unless they use `IS NULL`).

Answer (score 4):

The `IF` statement is a flow-control structure, that comes into play in procedural code, not in queries.

Here, you would typically use boolean logic in the `where` clause of the query.

```
where (:start_date is null or reg_date >= :start_date)
  and (:end_date   is null or reg_date <= :end_date  )
```

... where `:start_date` and `:end_date` represent the parameters of the query.

I am unsure about the use of the empty string in your pseudo-code to denote "missing" parameters; probably one would expect `null` values instead (a string and a date are two different datatypes).

Comment: The query in the question uses `""`, not `NULL`. It likely comes from a web form, which doesn't have a way of sending `NULL`, but you can leave the fields blank.

Comment: ... which is invalid in Oracle, @Barmar. Two consecutive **single** quotes represent an empty string, though, but - again in Oracle - it is equivalent to NULL. As people commented, it depends on which database OP really uses. If it is Oracle, then GMB put it right.

Comment: Am giving " " ,in case user will not give value...at that times parameters comes empty